# Solr autosuggest tutorial For Edge Ngram

Tags: solr, autosuggest

Can someone provide a link/blog/anything where I can find a step by step tutorial of Solr and autosuggest.

I want to understand how to complete configuring schema , configurations including field types analyzers and tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article specifically [on autosuggesters](http://romiawasthy.blogspot.fi/2014/06/configure-solr-suggester.html). And another one on doing [multi-field autosuggester](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/04/15/search-suggestions-with-solr-2/).

There are also several ways to implement autocomplete. You can use ngrams approach, which is what I use for [Solr/Lucene search-based documentation](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/index.html). You can find the source code for that on [Solr-Javadoc repository](https://github.com/arafalov/Solr-Javadoc).

There is [another one](http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/) doing ngrams and edge-ngrams from a couple of years ago.

You could also use [facets](http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/06/08/advanced-suggest-as-you-type-with-solr/) for some scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can you tell me one more thing. I created my own schema xml and config xml. I have solr4-8.1. Can you tell how to place these files and start server so that my solr uses these files.

Comment: If you are happy to call the new collection *collection1*, then just put it in an empty directory (say *mysolrhome*), inside *collection1* put directory *conf* and inside of that your two files. Start Solr server with -Dsolr.solr.home=path_to_mysolrhome. 

If you want a different name, you also need solr.xml file and core.properties in the correct places. Just search for those terms.

Comment: I was finally able to do it. Thanks